# App Script Tool: Trying to get all files URLs in the folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I`m trying to get output of all the files URLs form the current folder, but I only get URL of the first file from the forlder here:

```js
function listFolderContents() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Hub 2');
  var foldername = sheet.getRange('D160').getValue();
  var linkoutput = sheet.getRange('W160');
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername);
  var folder = folders.next();
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  Logger.log(linkoutput);
  var file;
  var link;
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    link = file.getUrl();
    linkoutput.setValue(link);
  }  
};
```

3 more things:

- I`d like to have this script looped through the whole column, so it would check each folder name in column D and output files links in the column W;
- the best outcome would be if it could output all the 3 links(as each folder would have only 3 files anyways) in the range of W:Y of the same row with the foder name;
- and the last if this script could run automatically without a need to open Scripts tool and running the code every time.
  thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For this question:

> and the last if this script could run automatically without a need to open Scripts tool and running the code every time. thanks in advance!

You can set a Trigger to run when the spreadsheet is opened. Or you could set time triggers, to run daily for example.

[image]

Regarding the code, It looks like your are setting the link url always to the same cell (W60).

Comment: Thanks, I`ll look into the trigger for repeating the script, but about the code, to be honest I`m a total beginner with this and I really need someone to give me a clue, how I could define the whole column and let it loop through the whole column, also why I only get the link from the first file, how can I get all files links???